# Many rows to one row result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I hope I'm explaining this well. I'm struggling with this query:

I have this table that is something like this:

```
InvoiceNum
Amount
Type  - where type could be item, shipping or tax.
```

So what I want returned is one row per invoice: InvoiceNum, ItemAmount, ShippingAmount, TaxAmount.

Here's an example:

```
Invoicenum Amount Type
1          $32    Item
1          $2     Shipping
1          $1     Tax
```

I would want returned:

```
InvoiceNum ItemAmount ShippingAmount TaxAmount 
1          $32        $2             $1
```

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us the table structure we could see more - as it stands I can't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can summarize rows with `group by`, and you can select specific rows using `case`:

```
select  InvoiceNum
,       sum(case when Type = 'Item' then Amount end) as ItemAmount
,       sum(case when Type = 'Shipping' then Amount end) as ShippingAmount
,       sum(case when Type = 'Tax' then Amount end) as TaxAmount
from    YourTable
group by
        InvoiceNum
```

The case statement returns `null` by default, and `sum` ignores nulls.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with group by and sum tricks (max works too) as @Andomar shows.

Alternatively, Microsoft SQL Server supports syntax for a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.90%29.aspx) operation that helps a bit in this type of query.  You still have to hard-code the column names though.

```
SELECT InvoiceNum, [Item] AS ItemAmount, [Shipping] AS ShippingAmount, [Tax] AS TaxAmount
FROM 
(SELECT InvoiceNum, Amount, Type FROM InvoiceTable ) i
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Amount)
  FOR Type IN ([Item], [Shipping], [Tax])
) AS pvt;
```